# Grails 3 Restful Link Generator (w/o the action)

Tags: rest, grails

Is there a way to reconfigure the Grails 3 Link Generator to create Restful links, i.e. `localhost:8080/book/{id}` rather than the old style that includes the action in the URL, `localhost:8080/book/show/{id}`?

I'd like to have restful URLs in the location headers of the responses to save actions.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this [Grails Restful Link Generator](https://gist.github.com/tonyerskine/8adfcac42fc1a54903a068ee20f9db42) as a workaround.  I'm not perfectly happy with it, but it's the best I've been able to come up with thus far.

**1. Create a trait in `src/main/groovy` that removes the superfluous action from the URL**

```
import grails.web.mapping.LinkGenerator

trait RestfulLinkGeneratorTrait {

    LinkGenerator grailsLinkGenerator

    String generateLink(Map map) {
        map.controller = map.controller ?: this.controllerName
        map.absolute = map.absolute ?: true
        map.action = map.action ?: "show"
        grailsLinkGenerator.link(map).replace("/$map.action", "")
    }
}
```

**2. Implement the `RestfulLinkGenerator` on your controller(s) and call `generateLink(id: obj.id)` to generate links.**

```
@Secured('ROLE_USER')
class BookController extends RestfulController implements RestfulLinkGeneratorTrait {

    //... other methods ...//

    @Transactional
    def save() {
        // ... save you resource ... //
        response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, generateLink(id: book.id))
        respond book, [status: CREATED, view: 'show']
    }

    //... other methods ...//

}
```